# MVC2, Entity Framework, & repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, repository-pattern

I'm trying to get a repository pattern working with MVC2 and EF. 
My problem is within the concrete repository. When I attempt to cast the EF query results as an IEnumerable collection of view-model entities:

```
Unable to cast object of type     
'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Data_Service.MediaReleases]' 
to type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestMVCWithFacory.Models.Entities.MediaReleaseModel]'.
```

I sense that's a bone-headed thing to try to do -- and it's something with Linq, and how deferred execution works, but I don't really understand the voodoo.

*So what is it that I'm mis-understanding there, and how do I address it?*

**The view-model:**

```
public class MediaReleaseModel
{
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string FullText { get; set; }
}
```

**The repository interface:**

```
public interface IMediaReleasesRepository
{
    IEnumerable<MediaReleaseModel> MediaReleases { get;}
}
```

**The concrete repository:**

```
public class MediaReleaseRepository : IMediaReleasesRepository
{
    private NewsEntities DataContext = new NewsEntities();
    private IEnumerable<MediaReleases> _MRs;

    public MediaReleaseRepository()
    {
        _MRs = from art in DataContext.MediaReleases select art;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MediaReleaseModel> MediaReleases
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<MediaReleaseModel>)_MRs; }
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMediaReleasesRepository _MRRepository;
    public HomeController()
    {
        _MRRepository= new MediaReleaseRepository();
    }

    public ViewResult index()
    {
        return View(_MRRepository.MediaReleases.ToList());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to cast collection of `MediaRelease`s to collection of `MediaReleaseModel`s. If `MediaReleaseModel` is a separate class, this can't be done just by casting. Generally, cast will succeed only in one inheritance chain or when [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx?ppud=4) are defined, which is not the case here.

What you need here is rewriting the `MediaRelease` fields to you model object (it can be automated using tools like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)), i.e. with help of LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<MediaReleaseModel> MediaReleases
{
    get
    {
        return _MRs.Select(x => new MediaReleaseModel() 
        {
            Prop1 = x.Prop1 
            /* etc. */
        });
    }
}
```

One suggestion at the side: it's better not to have logic like that in constructor, creating objects should be cheap operation and it's a bit strange when the data are fetched before they are really needed.

Comment: Thanks. Re: your last line: you're referring to the linq statement in MediaReleaseRepository, correct? (not calling the repository in the controller constructor?)

Comment: Yes. Generally, constructors should only collect dependencies and avoid doing "real work". Your query can be easily moved to `MediaReleases` property.